# The issue is with the top shadow in the TextArea

Tags: java, javafx

[image]I am trying to beautify a TextArea, but there is always a shadow at the top of the TextArea that I want to eliminate.
This is my CSS code:

```
.text-area-ui{
    /*-fx-effect: innershadow(one-pass-box, rgba(128, 128, 128, 0.67), 5, 0, 1, 1);*/
    -fx-background-radius: 3;
    -fx-background-color: white;
}
.text-area-ui:focused{
    /*-fx-effect: dropshadow(two-pass-box, #0075FF, 5, 0, 1, 1)!important;*/
}
.text-area-ui .content {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
}
```

I have consulted the JavaFX CSS documentation, but I cannot resolve it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you check the hierarchy of text area as in below image, the shadow is actually the background color (gradient) of ContentView.

[image]

So to turn if off, just set the ContentView background color to white in your current css.

```
.text-area-ui .content {
    -fx-background-insets: 0;
    -fx-background-color:white;
}
```

Comment: You use this Fxplorer software is your own writing, it feels very useful, Can you share it with me.

Comment: @雨夜带刀不带伞 The _Fxplorer_ in the screenshot looks similar to [Scenic View](https://github.com/JonathanGiles/scenic-view) (I don't believe the two are the same software, but I couldn't find _Fxplorer_ from a quick Google search, and _Scenic View_ is readily available on GitHub).

Comment: @Slaw you are right. This tool is built by taking the inspiration from ScenicView. ScenicView has some limitations. Particularly for inspecting Popups(in ComboBox, Menus, etc) which is a major blocker for me. Also there is not clear details about the background & border details of node. So used the technique (RMI) that is used in ScenicView and developed a tool from scratch as per my needs. A quick readme about the tool can be found [here](https://github.com/SaiPradeepDandem/Fxplorer/). I will publish this once I clean the code.